# How to fix performance issue in azure search

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cognitive-search

I am implementing azure search in my application to provide autosuggestion feature like google, big, and amazon. I have implemented the same available github code using below URL.All is working fine but getting result in more than 1.5 second for each term of sentence.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started/tree/master/DotNetHowToAutocomplete

Currently I am using two indexes for searching and created in basic tier. Below is code

```
 public ActionResult Suggest(bool highlights, bool fuzzy, string term)
    {
        InitSearch();

        // Call suggest API and return results
        SuggestParameters sp = new SuggestParameters()
        {
            UseFuzzyMatching = fuzzy,
            Top = 5,
            Filter="name eq 'testid'",
            OrderBy=new List<string>() { "Date desc"}

        };


         if (highlights)
        {
            sp.HighlightPreTag = "<b>";
            sp.HighlightPostTag = "</b>";
        }
        DocumentSuggestResult suggestResult = _indexClient1.Documents.Suggest(term, "index1",sp);
        if (suggestResult.Results.Count<5)
        {

            SuggestParameters sp2 = new SuggestParameters()
            {
                UseFuzzyMatching = fuzzy,
                Top = 5- suggestResult.Results.Count,
                Filter = "Product eq 'PAAS'",
                OrderBy = new List<string>() { "Count desc" }

            };
            if (highlights)
            {
                sp2.HighlightPreTag = "<b>";
                sp2.HighlightPostTag = "</b>";
            }
            DocumentSuggestResult suggestResult2= _indexClient2.Documents.Suggest(term, "index2", sp2);
            suggestResult.Results = suggestResult.Results.Union(suggestResult2.Results).Distinct().ToList();
           // final = suggestResult.Results.GroupBy(s => s.Text, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
        }


        // Convert the suggest query results to a list that can be displayed in the client.
        List<string> suggestions = suggestResult.Results.Select(x => x.Text).Distinct().ToList();

        return new JsonResult
        {
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
            Data = suggestions
        };
    }
```

To test it- when I am typing any word it's taking too much time in populating results around 1.5 to 1.8 seconds, it's working like other web app searchbox.

Timing I am checking using inspect element of chrome browser. Attaching sreenshot.[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsTA8.jpg)

Please suggest.

Comment: You haven't really shown any detail (aside from a link to a sample). Without more details, it's really just going to get you guesses. Also: have you tried increasing the tier to see if that makes a difference? What have you compared it to, to consider the performance "slow"? How did you benchmark? Please edit your question accordingly. As currently written, this is unfortunately off-topic as "too broad."

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for quick reply. I added sample code and provided details. Please suggest me if any other way to test the performance locally.

Comment: Can you share how you measured the 1.5 seconds?

Comment: @ramero-MSFT Thanks for response. screenshot shared, I am measuring it using chrome browser. Also I can feel it's not appearing quickly as other web app searching functionality work. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question on another post: [Why is Azure Search taking 1400 miliiseconds to return query results for simple query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53840961/why-is-azure-search-taking-1400-miliiseconds-to-return-query-results-for-simple/53859272#53859272)

The main thing is, you shouldn't be using the Chrome timer to measure the performance of azure search. Use the "elapsed-time" field of the HTTP response you receive (take an average over multiple call), since it accurately tells you how much time was spent getting your results from azure search. The chrome timer can be affected by your network/machine configuration. If that doesn't help, you can follow the other tips I suggested in the post I linked above.